# If $T^{2} = 0$, what can you say about the relation of the range of $T$ to the null space of $T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $\textbf{F}$ and $T$ a linear operator on $V$. If $T^{2} = 0$, what can you say about the relation of the range of $T$ to the null space of $T$? Give an example of a linear operator on $\textbf{R}^{2}$ such that $T^{2} = 0$, but $T\neq 0$.

**MY ATTEMPT (EDIT)**

Let us suppose that $\alpha\in V$. According to the proposed relation, if $T\alpha \in R$, then $T^{2}\alpha = T(T\alpha) = 0$, thus $T\alpha\in N$, that is to say, $R\subset N$.

As an example, we can consider the following operator: $T(1,0) = (0,1)$ and $T(0,1) = (0,0)$. Consequently, $T^{2}(1,0) = T(0,1) = (0,0)$ and $T^{2}(0,1) = T(0,0) = (0,0)$, which means that $T(x,y)\neq(0,0)$, but $T^{2}(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: Your example $T(x,y)=(0,x)$ is a good one.  It rotates the $x$-component to the $y$-axis and kills the $y$-component

Comment: For the first question, you should be able to prove that one of $N$ and $R$ is a subspace of the other.

Comment: An operator that satisfies $T^k=0$ for some positive integer $k$ is called *nilpotent.* The characteristic polynomial of such an operator is $x^k$, and hence zero is its only eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T^2=0\implies \operatorname{Range}T\subset\operatorname{ker}T$.

For the second part, consider $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0):

Take an operator $T$ such that it maps the first basis to zero and the second basis to the first one, $T(e_1)=0, T(e_2)=e_1$. It is easy to check that $T\neq 0$ but $T^2=0$.

Comment: I have changed the title, since I am more concerned about the first question instead of the second.